# In Ruby, if we define "c=(foo)" and it returns foo + 1, why is this not assigned to d = (self.c = 3)?

Tags: ruby

the code is

```
def c=(foo)
  p "hello"
  return foo + 1
end

p self.c = 3
d = (self.c = 3)
p d
```

and it will print out 3 only... in other words, the returned value 4 is not assigned to `d`, why?

Comment: Is that c= in a class? Does "hello" get printed twice?

Comment: When the hell are you actually going to use code like this? In the real world you need to write more readable code, ideally with fewer random side effects.

Comment: It is not my code.  I am reading a Rails plugin called Restful Authentication and it has construct like that (with the `return`, but some assignment statement).  In Rails, don't we need to frequently look at other people's code as there are plugin and gems... (and at work in general too)

Answer (score 7):

Setters return their argument (or right operand, depending on how you look at it) — always.

Comment: That is: if you call them using setter syntax. If you call them using `send`, they return their actual return value.

Answer (score 3):

Methods like `def foo=(bar)` cannot return a value. It's probably to allow multi-assignment:

```
a = self.foo = 3
# a will be 3, independent of what foo returns
```