# Over-riding the substring update operator in Ruby's String class

Tags: ruby, string, variable-assignment, operator-keyword, overriding

I'd like to implement a functional version of the String class.
Specifically, if you update a substring I want to clone the String, perform the update
and return the resulting new string so I can chain/telescope the operations.
The functionality is easy to code:

```
class FString < String
  alias zap []=
  def update( i, v )
    print "\"#{self}\".update( #{i}, #{v} )\n"
    (c = self.dup).zap( i, v )
    c
  end
  def []=( i, v )
    print "\"#{self}\"[#{i}] = #{v}\n"
    self.update(i,v)
  end
end

a = FString.new "test"
b = a.update( 2..3, 'XX' )
c = (a[2..3] = 'XX')

print "#{a}\n#{b}\n#{c}\n"
```

What I'm stuck on is that I'd like to use my update method instead of the default []= operator.
But if you run the above code you get the following output:

```
"test".update( 2..3, XX )
"test"[2..3] = XX
"test".update( 2..3, XX )
test
teXX
XX
```

Can someone explain why using the update method directly gives different results from using []= (which immediately calls update) ?

Comment: Amazing question. This is bizarre behaviour. I don't have an answer yet and have been playing for a while but just wanted to point out that your code seems fine. The following works great: range = Range.new(2, 3); c = (a.send :[]=, range, 'XX');

Comment: [This other recent stackoverflow question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5111388/in-ruby-if-we-define-c-foo-and-it-returns-foo-1-why-is-this-not-assigned) looks similar.  One answer says that setter methods always returns the right operand.  I'm guessing `[]=` falls into the same category as a regular setter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is simple. See:

```
c = (a[2..3] = 'XX')
```

The method []= always returns the second argument, `'XX'` (like any method that finishs with `=`) because it is a assignment operator. You will probably need to undef `[]=` to avoid this error.

Comment: But I overrode that definition in the FString class?

Comment: I threw in a undef []= after the alias but it makes no difference. :-/

Comment: Have you removed `def []=(i, v) ... end`? If not, you are just redefining the method. I tried and the `undef []=` and it works.